# Does Eclipse package includes javac.exe

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is what I read on this forum:

**JRE:**

It's needed to run Java programs. You can't compile Java programs with it .

**JDK:**
It's the full featured Software Development Kit for Java, including JRE, and the compilers and tools (like JavaDoc, and Java Debugger) to create and compile programs.

On my office laptop I only have the JRE folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6  and no JDK.

But I have Eclipse ( Indigo ) which I use for writing and executing my Java programs.

My Questions is does this Eclipse package includes the java compiler javac.exe ?

I am wondering how I am able to compile and run java programs on Eclipse without JDK on my laptop.

Thanks to all in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Well just open your eclipse instance and see java configurations in the parameters

Comment: That depends on what version of Eclipse you've downloaded. Usually, JDK is stored in C:\Program Files\Java\ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Eclipse packages their own compiler called ecj, as part of the [Java Development Tools (JDT)](https://eclipse.org/jdt/core/). The link says (in part)

> An incremental Java compiler. Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it is based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler. In particular, it allows to run and debug code which still contains unresolved errors.

Comment: Thanks Elliott for taking out time and replying.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has its own Compiler. You no need to install a JDK seperately.